# In a tabbed interface, where should I put the record count

Tags: tabs, counter

I have an interface for an order which has many different relationships. We have a section with tabs for each of the relationship types and I want to put the record count of each tab in the tab title. Is there a standard convention for putting the record count before or after the title? My gut says I should put it after the title, but I've seen other systems put it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of the convention but notable examples of showing something like a record count after the title are:

- Microsoft Outlook
- GMail
- Stack Exchange